# In jQuery I want to do some additional processing on a promise result, then return a promise - and do this in an encapsulated way

Tags: jquery

In a function I need to make a request which returns a promise, when that is resolved do some additional processing on what was resolved and return the whole thing as a promise.

Something like this:

```
//returns promise
function getData() 
{
    var xhr = $.ajax(...);
    xhr.done(
        function(result) {
            //do some processing on result e.g.
            result = sort(result);  
        }
    )
    return xhr;

}

//usage
var xhr = getData();
xhr.done(
    function(result) {
        //here i want to see the sorted result
    }

)
```

This code isn't going to work. I will see result - not the sorted result. The sorted result is not returned from getData()

I think that what I need to do is in getData() create a new Promise (Deferred?), attach my ajax request to that in some way, have a handler that does my additional processing - and then return the whole thing as a promise. Something like (in sketch form):

```
function getData() 
{
    var def = $.deferred();
    var xhr = $.ajax(...);
    def.attachPromise(xhr);
    def.onPromiseResolved = function(promiseResult) {
        result = sort(promiseResult);
    }
    return def;

}
```

Am I on the right tracks at all?

Nb. I want to do the sorting in getData  this is the problem. I don't want to just return the original promise and do the additional processing on that. I want all this logic to take place in getData which returns a promise.

Comment: It seems I can do exactly what  i want by chaining the then() calls. The data can be modified in the first function passed to then and returned and the next chained then() will get this modified data. As per this link https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-jquery-deferred-objects/ (the example with the README file). It is not necessary to use the Deferred object.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't need it for my precise requirement which I could solve by chaining the then calls. However I did figure out how to do what I wanted. Examples of both below. [This link help me](https://www.sitepoint.com/introduction-jquery-deferred-objects/).

//1. Chaining then:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({
url: '/test.json',
dataType: 'json',
method: 'GET'
});

xhr.then(function(result) {
    //modify the result here
    result["a"] = "new value";  
    //the modified result is now forwarded to the next chained then
    return result;  
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result); //the modified result
})
```

//2. Using a deferred to enable us to modify promise data

```
var xhr2 = $.ajax(
{
url: '/test.json',
dataType: 'json',
method: 'GET'
});

xhr2.then(function() {
    //the deferred resolver function is passed
    //the data from getJSON because we've used that
    //as the resolver for the getJSON
    var def = $.Deferred(function (defer) {
        $.getJSON('/test.json').then(defer.resolve); 
    });
    //by adding a then to the deferred we ensure that this 
    //is run when the deferred is resolved and we modify the return value
    def.then(function(data) {
        data["a"] = "new value"; 
    })
    //finally we return the deferred's promise object
    return def.promise(); 
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result); //the modified value from getJSON
})
```